# docker ha proxy for port routing

Tags: linux, docker, port, haproxy

Docker is running in 80:80

```
image: 6d/wordpress:1.1
ports: ['80:80']
```

from the network the request will reach to 9092 port. How can I route the request to the exact docker port. Do I need to use haproxy, if yes, how can I configure that?

Comment: Are you trying to reach your WordPress image through port 9092? If so it'd be a matter of simply changing 80:80 to 9092:80

Answer (score 0):

as the user Garfield Tong said, you should change the `docker-compose.yml` or the `dockerfile` and set ports `9092:80` (host-port:container-port) and if it were a dockerfile when you launch it use the `-p` option to set the port `9092:8`, for example:

```
docker run -p 9092:80 nameofservice
```